# Is bijection a transitive relationship?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, relations

As doing some cardinality proofs I began to wonder if bijection is a transitive relationship. For simplicity I tried to use real functions to explore the question.

Consider the bijective functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $ g: B \rightarrow C$ is it a necessity that exits a bijective $h: A \rightarrow C$ ?

I tried composing functions:

If
$$ \forall b \in B,  \exists ! a \in A  | f(a) = b $$
$$ \forall c \in C,  \exists ! B \in B  | g(b) = c $$

Then
$$ g(b) = c \iff g(f(a)) = c $$
Defining $ h:= g  \circ f$, then h is a bijection $A \rightarrow C$

I have three questions:

1 - What I tried was correct?

2 - If so, then is there any way to generalize it?

3 - Is bijection a transitive relationship?

Comment: Quick note: to show bijectivity, between $A$ and $B$, technically you need to state that $\forall b\in B, \exists ! a\in A \mid f(a)=b$, not the other way around. Likewise for $B$ and $C$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, what you tried was correct.
2. Generalize it how? A bijection is an example of an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) between sets.
3. Yes, for exactly the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: 2 - For any kinda of 3 sets A, B and C. If A is bijective to B and B is bijective to C, then A is bijective to C. I worked under the Real Numbers because I knew everything was the same _kind_. Would it also work if I had a ${\mathbb{R}}^{n}$, $\mathbb{C}$ or other kinds of sets in the mix? Assuming the two first bijections were true

Comment: In your post, you didn't specify that the sets were subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. So you already generalized it to all sets! :)

Comment: It was simpler than I thought. Many thanks!